# Configure OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider via Autofac 4.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin, autofac

I must integrate Oauth with Autofac. But something goes wrong. I think I understand why, but I don't know how to solve it. I let you see my code.

**My Autofac Config**

```
{
    builder.RegisterType<CustomAuthorizationServerProvider>()
            .PropertiesAutowired()
            .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<MyBusinessObj>()
           .As<IMyBusinessObj>()
           .InstancePerRequest()
           .PropertiesAutowired();

    //IMySessionObj is a prop inside MyBusinessObj
    builder.RegisterType<MySessionObj>()
           .As<IMySessionObj>()
           .InstancePerRequest()
           .PropertiesAutowired();

    //IMyUnitOfWorkObjis a prop inside MyBusinessObj
    builder.RegisterType<MyUnitOfWorkObj>()
           .As<IMyUnitOfWorkObj>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

    ...
}
```

**Startup.cs**

I have the classic configuration plus the resolution of my `authorizationServerProvider`.. As you can see, I resolve it in the container... because it is a singleton.

```
app.UseAutofacMiddleware(_container);
app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);

var oauthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    ...,
    Provider = _container.Resolve<CustomAuthorizationServerProvider>()
};

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oauthServerOptions);

app.UseWebApi(config);
```

**CustomAuthorizationServerProvider.cs**

This is how I have implemented my `CustomAuthorizationServerProvider`.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationServerProvider: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var autofacLifetimeScope = OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(context.OwinContext);
        var myBusinessObj = autofacLifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyBusinessObj>();
        var xxx = myBusinessObj.DoWork();
        ...
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var myBusinessObj = autofacLifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyBusinessObj>();
        var xxx = myBusinessObj.DoWork();
        ...
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
}
```

Here I solve my `IMyBusinessObj` in a lifetimescope, not in the container. This object is responsible (indirectly) to connect to db, access the session, access the cache and so on... so it cannot be a singleton.

I need it would have a lifetime per request. 
So here the problems.. Two problems there are in my configuration.

1. I have a `InstancePerRequest` object inside a `SingleInstance` object. I cannot do that. [Troubleshooting Per-Request Dependencies](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#troubleshooting-per-request-dependencies)
2. I effectively cannot have a `InstancePerRequest` object when I configure oauth in the startup... because in that context does not exist a request yet.

So.. I have understood which are my problems.

Any idea or tips?
Thank you

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very similar issue if not the same.  I was able to resolve it by doing the following:

**1.** Do not resolve `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` directly from the container.  Instead, use `IDependencyResolver`.  In your example:

```cs
var oauthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    ...,
    Provider = (IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider)resolver.GetService(typeof(IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider)),
};
```

This requires that you have correctly configured `HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver`:

```cs
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

... // Configure unrelated

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();    

... // set Autofac registrations 

var container = builder.Build();

config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// THIS is where you configure OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions, using IDependencyResolver to resolve IOAuthorizationServerProvider instead of IContainer
ConfigureAuth(app, config.DependencyResolver);
```

**2.** I was using dynamic assembly scanning to configure certain Autofac module registrations.  I inadvertently was scanning for classes ending with "Provider" and registering them as `RequestPerInstance()`.  This was a problem for me, as it was re-registering my `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` as a per-request instance, which is unable to be resolved during `Startup()` code.

Problem code which I replaced with individual registrations:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(executingAssembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Provider"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

**3.** Check properties of `MySessionObj`, and see what dependencies Autofac is resolving (if any).  Make sure that you are explicitly registering dependencies as `InstancePerRequest()`.

By using `OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(context.OwinContext);`, you are resolving dependencies to the "AutoFacWebRequest" lifetime scope, and not the root scope.  As a result, my understanding is dependencies resolved to this lifetime scope should be disposed after the request has finished and shouldn't cause future problems with your application.

**4.** I am not sure what properties are being autowired for your `CustomAuthorizationServerProvider` object, but assuming you did not post a complete code sample for this class, I would try removing `PropertiesAutowired()` from it's Autofac registration and inside the object continue to use `OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(context.OwinContext);` to resolve these other properties if possible.

Could you provide specific detail about what the error or error message you are observing is?